# box2d slide body from another

Tags: box2d

I am trying  to connect two bodies, allowing to slide one from another, here`s illustration:

[image]

So as you can see, orange body can slide left-right to certain limits (initial state and final state)

Here is in real example of such "feature" - crane arms:

[image]

Arms are sliding one from another, extending whole arm length.

Will be grateful for ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [prismatic joints](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-prismatic) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I should not have missed that.